# how to make the position of a subclassed UINavigationController overlapped status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a subclass called SubNav which inherits from UINavigationController.
When I make it like:

```
window.rootViewController = subNav
```

it shows the NavigationBar at the below of status bar. But in fact I want make its position at the 0,0. not under the status bar 0,20.

But mostly ios7-designed apps in the App Store I saw ,those UINavigationBar is under the status bar.

```
SubNav : UINavigationController
```

I'm sorry with my poor English,but I'm confusing with it for several days.

Comment: Can you show screenshots of what you have and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 7, the status bar is actually in a layer above the underlying bar or view controller view. If the underlying view controller is presenting a scroll view based view - such as an actual scroll view or table view or collection view - then the framework auto inserts additional offsets.  Look into the topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide properties.

You didn't say what view controller type you are using, but assuming you are using a collection view, table view or scroll view based view controller, you would see this auto offsetting behavior.

Again assuming that that is the case, one thing you can do is to set the property:

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

Once you do that, your underlying view will be placed at an origin of 0,0

You'll need to adjust its frame thru the standard means if that's not where you want it.